# How do I check if dataTaskWithRequest is complete?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, nsurlsession

I'm new to iOS programming and trying to create my first app. I am fetching some data from a server using

```
  var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,

        completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
```

I understand that all code in the completionHandler closure is executed when the task is completed. From my ViewController, I want to check if this task has been completed, and not load a table until it has. How do I check if this task has been completed?

I guess I could have the completionHandler set some global boolean variable to true when it runs, and I could check this variable in my ViewController, but I feel like there is a better way to do it with built in functionality, I just don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view controller doesn't need to know when `completionHandler` is called. All you do is you have `completionHandler` actually dispatch a `tableView.reload()` back to the main queue (which then triggers the calling of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods). It's the `completionHandler` that initiates the UI update, not the other way around:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    // check for errors and parse the `data` here

    // when done
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reload()  // this results in all of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods to be called
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: AH! that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!